# What is the error using Columns with VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

Look I have this code in VBA:

```
Sub Test1()
For i = 1 To 6
    Cells(1, i).Value = 34
    Cells(i, 1).Value = 34
    Columns(1, i).Value = 34        'Here is an error: Why?
Next i
End Sub
```

There is an error using Columns, Why?

Thanks

Comment: Columns actually only accepts one argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error using Columns that way because it only takes one input, not two

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197266(v=office.15).aspx

A correct use of Columns would be like...

Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Font.Bold = True

As a direct example if you change your code to the below, it will put 34 in every row of column A

```
Sub Test1()

    Columns(1).Value = 34

End Sub
```

Comment: OK, but then the Excel is wrong, because offers the second argument when you open the parentheses in the yellow tag.

Comment: Well since Excel is throwing an error, it's obviously the wrong way to use columns in this instance. See above for a bug free example.

Comment: The intellisense is confused because Columns returns a Range object, whose default property (Item) allows for row and column arguments. However, the Range returned by Columns doesn't work the same way.